# How to get multiple items in a PHP stream?

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and am trying to echo the contents of a stream. I am able to get the contents if there isn't duplicates, but if there are duplicates I get the error,

```
Notice: Undefined Index
```

Here is my code,

```
<?php

     $url = "stream.php";

     $json = file_get_contents($url);
     $streamInfo = json_decode($json,true)

     echo $streamInfo["docID"];

?>
```

This outputs,

```
451287
```

But when I try to `echo $streamInfo[list][color];` it gives me the error:

```
Notice: Undefined Index 'color'
```

Here is the `stream.php` file, I can't edit the contents of this file.

```
{
  "docID": 451287,

  "list": [
     {
       "id": 85,
       "color": blue
     },
     {
       "id": 47,
       "color": red
     },
     {
       "id": 12,
       "color": green
     }
   ]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your usage of `stream` is weird

Comment: This question isn't related to streams, but you're missing an array index to access data within `list` e.g. `$stream['list'][$i]['color']` where `$i` is an index of one of the items.

Comment: What is your expected result?  Do you want the `id`s and the `color`s? or just the colors?  You can't echo an array.  Without knowing your expected result, your question is Unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list is an array so you can do `echo $streamInfo['list'][0]['color'];` to get the first item.

to get all the items in the list back you will need to iterate over the list

something like this will get an array of all colors:

```
$colors = array_map(function($listItem){
    return $listItem['color'];
},$streamInfo['list']);

var_dump($colors); // returns ['blue','red','green'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the trouble with your json input is that the structure of the `list` subarray is altered depending on how many items it contains.  To determine the right method for accessing the subarray data, you only need to check if `id` or `color` is an immediate key of `list`.  `isset()` will quickly do this job for you.  When there are multiple items, the immediate keys of `list` will be numeric.  In these cases, `array_column()` and `implode()` do a great job of isolating the values and generating a comma-separated string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sT46v))

```
$jsons=[
    'Single'=>'{"docID":451287,"list":{"id":77,"color":"pink"}}',
    'Multiple'=>'{"docID":451287,"list":[{"id":85,"color":"blue"},{"id":47,"color":"red"},{"id":12,"color":"green"}]}'
];

foreach($jsons as $type=>$json){
    $array=json_decode($json,true);
    if(isset($array['list']['color'])){
        echo "Type = $type, Value = {$array['list']['color']}";
    }else{
        echo "Type = $type, Values = ",implode(', ',array_column($array['list'],'color'));
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Type = Single, Value = pink
Type = Multiple, Values = blue, red, green
```